# Aspose, access last piece of text written by the DocumentBuilder

Tags: c#, aspose

I am loading a template *.docx file into the DocumentBuilder and then moving to a known merge field. I then use docBuilder.Writeln("some text") in place of the merge field. How would I then access the last piece of text I wrote to either delete or modify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try using the following code:

```
Document doc = new Document(filePath);
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);
// Move cursor to MergeField and remove it
builder.MoveToMergeField("mf");
// Create a Bookmark
builder.StartBookmark("bm");
// Write something
builder.Write("Some text");
builder.EndBookmark("bm");
// Access content of Bookmark
Console.WriteLine(doc.Range.Bookmarks["bm"].Text);
```

Hope, this helps. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: In my case the "Some text" is a carriage return, when I retrieve it using the Bookmark strategy I'd like to delete it.

Comment: Since you can't attach files in this forum. Please post this query in [Aspose.Words forum](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.words-product-family/75/showforum.aspx). Please zip and attach your input Word file and source code in your thread for testing. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.